# How to call drop down list by ajax call request when selected value changed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, ado.net

I work on web app mvc .NET framework I face issue i can't call function `GetSelectedDropDownChanged` when drop down selected changed .

I put break point to function `GetSelectedDropDownChanged` on controller `WorkforceRequests`

but it not hit or catched so what is issue

so what I try is :

```
  <th>
    <select class="form-control" id="statusselect" name="statusselectName">
       
        <option value="1">Pending Request</option>
        <option value="2">All requests </option>
    </select>
</th>
```

when select from drop down I expect to call it ajax request call to function `WorkforceRequests` controller  `WorkforceRequests` :

```
<script>
  $(function () {
        $(document)
            .on('change', '#statusselect', function () {
                var valueofDropDown = $(this).val();
                var url = '/WorkforceRequests/GetSelectedDropDownChanged';
                var dataToSend = { selectedValue: valueofDropDown }

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: dataToSend,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (dataReceived) {
                        //update control on View
                        var receivedValue = dataReceived.myResult;
                        $('YourControlIDToUpdate').val(receivedValue);
                    }
                })
            });
    };
</script>
```

function i call from ajax request as below :

```
public class WorkforceRequestsController : Controller
    {   
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetSelectedDropDownChanged(string selectedValue) 
        {
            List<WorkforceRequest> workforceRequest = new List<WorkforceRequest>();
            if (selectedValue == "1")
            {
              
                                      
            workforceRequest = Workforce.GetPendingOnPalnningSection();
                       
                        
            }
            else
                 workforceRequest = Workforce.GetAllRequestsData();

            return Json(new { myResult = workforceRequest }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

data will returned as list from ajax call from function `GetSelectedDropDownChanged` ON table id `dtbl`

```
<table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkforceRequestID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Section)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredPosition)
            </th>
           
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
               
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkforceRequestID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredPosition)
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

**Last Updated**

I change my code inside view.cshtml to :

```
 @model IEnumerable<HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.WorkforceRequest>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pending Requests";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Pending Requests</h2>
<hr />
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.msg))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        @ViewBag.msg
    </div>
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.errorMsg))
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @ViewBag.errorMsg
    </div>
}
@if (Session[BLL.Common.SessionKeys.RoleCode].ToString() == "REC" || Session[BLL.Common.SessionKeys.RoleCode].ToString() == "PLNG")
{
    <th>
        <select class="form-control" id="statusselect" >
            @*<option>Select Status</option>*@
            <option value="1">Pending Request</option>
            <option value="2">All requests </option>
        </select>
    </th>
}
<table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WorkforceRequestID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Section)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RequiredPosition)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JobTitle)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReportingTo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NationalityCategory)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusRemark)
            </th>
            <th>
                Requestor
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.WorkforceRequestID })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WorkforceRequestID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Section)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequiredPosition)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobTitle)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportingTo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NationalityCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusRemark)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedByName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>

</table>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   
@section scripts
    {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#statusselect").change(function () {
                var valueofDropDown = $("#statusselect").val();
                console.log(valueofDropDown);
                var url = @Url.Action("GetSelectedDropDownChanged", "WorkforceRequests");
                var dataToSend = { selectedValue: valueofDropDown }

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: dataToSend,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function (dataReceived) {
                        //update control on View
                        var receivedValue = dataReceived.myResult;
                        $('YourControlIDToUpdate').val(receivedValue);
                    }
                })
            });
    }
    </script>
}
```

**Issue still not solved yet**

Comment: Do you have any error on the console? Are you sure that the js code is called? To check add some console.log in the js code and look if it appears in the console.

Comment: it not give me any error message console

Comment: i add console.log(value) to    $(function () {
        $(document)
            .on('change', '#statusselect', function () {
                var valueofDropDown = $(this).val();
                console.log(valueofDropDown); it not catched or hitted so what i do

Comment: I would change your entry code to  _$(document).ready(function () { $("#statusselect").change(function () { StatusSelectChange(); });_ moving all the code in a named function created in a separate js file. This will allow an easier js debugging directly inside Visual Studio

Comment: let us start by console.log value it not get any value when change select drop down so what i do

Comment: After moving everything in a separate js file remember to include that file in the script section like _script src="~/js/myapp.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>_

Comment: can any one help me please

Comment: i make js file separate and add it on my page but issue not still yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ahmed abdelaziz please check below code

you write a url before after get the value

```
                var valueofDropDown = $(this).val();  
                var url = '/WorkforceRequests/GetSelectedDropDownChanged?selectedValue='+valueofDropDown;
```

have you check this one because I am not able to show in your code

```
@section scripts {
    //stuff
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: so what control i will assign here on this line $('YourControlIDToUpdate').val(receivedValue);

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz have you check console.log inside script